# Making Dropdown using API feedback

Tags: flutter, dart

i've been looking for how to make a dropdown list from data I've got from the API response. can you help me figure it out?

### Here's where I call the API

```
Future<List<RekDat>> _getRekDat() async {
    var data = await GetRek();
    var jsonData = json.decode(data);
    var jsonProduk = jsonData["VALUE"];
    List<RekDat> rekdat = [];

    for (var u in jsonProduk) {
      RekDat rekDat = RekDat(u["info_b"]);

      rekdat.add(rekDat);
    }
    return rekdat;
  }
```

### The Class

```
class RekDat {
  final String info_b];

  RekDat(this.info_b);
}
```

### and the response I want to show

```
"VALUE": [
        {
            "info_b": "A",
        },
        {
            "info_b": "B",
        },
        {
            "info_b": "M",
        }
    ],
```

Answer (score 1):

Obviously your jsons value field contains a list

```
List a = yourjson["VALUE"];
```

Then a's each item map. If you want to show it as dropdown item we need to convert map to string

```
import 'dart:convert';
String at = json.encode(a[0]); // now this is string, you can pass to dropdown item
```

Then you can implement your dropdown however you like. The trick point is you need to pass list to dropdown menu.

EDIT:

```
List somelist = [] ;

a.forEach((element) { 
   String at = json.encode(element);
   somelist.add(at);
    
})

;
```

Comment: this shows `Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'length' was called on null.`

Comment: what you get when print(a) ?

Comment: no no it fixed, but it only print A but not the B and M, also it print all the things include the info_b

Comment: `Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'add' was called on null.` another error appears

Comment: change it List somelist = [];

Comment: okay this one fixed, i have 2 dropdown and another one have more then 1 value inside each, how to take only 1 of them?

Comment: a is list a[index] is a map. Take keys and values by using map methods. a[index].keys and a[index].values . Have a look for this article https://coflutter.com/dart-how-to-get-keys-and-values-from-map/  If this post resolved your issue, you can check the tick for resolved to inform others